# Delete text between 2 delimiters with AWK

Tags: awk

I have a file like this:

```
start of my file
Some lines
#start
other lines
blabla other lines
#end
end of my file
```

I would like to delete everything between `#start` and `#end` (`#start` and `#end` included) and export the result to a file.

Expected result :

```
start of my file
Some lines
end of my file
```

I know how to make a selection between delimiters

```
awk '/#start/,/#end/'
```

but I can't do the deletion.

edit : I don't agree with the closure of the question.  The link given contains an answer with `sed`, which is not the purpose of my question since I am asking to do it with `awk`. Even if the result is the same, it is not an answer to my question.

Comment: what is the expected output if there is no `#end` line? or is every `#start` line guaranteed to have a matching `#end` line? can a `#start/#end` pair be embedded within another `#start/#end` pair and if so should the deletions be based on the `inner` or `outer` pair?  can 2 sets of `#begin/#end` pairs overlap each other and if so how should the lines be processed? are you only interested in lines that ***start*** with `#begin/#end` or should we also process lines where there may be characters before the `#begin/#end` strings? (and if so, do we delete the entire lines or just part of the lines)

Comment: I use this command to generate vhost and delete parts according to their usage. It's a personal thing so there will always be an `#end`.
Assuming the number of lines is fixed, I could specify that n lines should be deleted after `#start`. 
I didn't think I could do this with `sed`, thanks for the solution.

Comment: `sed '/^#start/,/^#end/d' file` would do the job as shown in dupe link as well.

Comment: New dupe link provided that covers awk, sed and perl tools for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
awk '/#start/,/#end/'
```

is shorthand for

```
awk '/#start/,/#end/ { print $0 }'
```

If the implied default action is not the one you want, spell out what you do want.

```
awk '/#start/,/#end/ { next } 1'
```

says to print all lines (by way of another shorthand, `1`, which selects the default action for all lines by virtue of having an address expression which is true for all lines) but skip that for lines in the region (`next` is the instruction to discard the current input line).

Comment: I get `awk: cmd. line:1: error: `continue' is not allowed outside a loop` with GNU Awk 5.1.0

Comment: Maybe you meant `next`?

Comment: Duh, thanks, too much Python (or rather, probably, too little Awk) lately.

Comment: Using `{next} 1` and `if` works. I select the `next` version as the answer as it is shorter and I think more efficient in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works:

```
awk 'BEGIN { p = 1 } 
     {
      if (/^#start/) { p = 0 } ;
      if (p == 1) { print } ;
      if (/^#end/) { p = 1 }
     }' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Using `{next} 1` and `if` works. I select the `next` version as the answer as it is shorter and I think more efficient in terms of performance.

Comment: Sure, whatever solution makes most sense to you, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

A pair of `sed` ideas:

```
sed -n '/#start/,/#end/!p' file
sed    '/#start/,/#end/d'  file
```

Both generate:

```
start of my file
Some lines
end of my file
```

**NOTE:**

- keep in mind that if there is a `#start` line but no `#end` line, all of the answers (so far) will delete everything from `#start` to the end of file
- if the requirement is to remove lines *only if both* `#start` and `#end` exist, this can be done but it will require a bit more work